# Display the location in cell using the longitude and latitude response from server

Tags: ios, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have a response of the server "longitude and latitude", I can also display it to the cell. But I need the address to be displayed, not the longitude and latitude. How can I do that?

Here is the response:

```
015-12-06 12:54:45.593 smartschool[249:11801] Item latitude_: 14.937681666666666
2015-12-06 12:54:45.593 smartschool[249:11801] Item longitude_: 121.02107833333334
```

I display the longitude and latitude to the cell using this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TableIdentifier";

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [_child_info objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    Child *cell = (Child *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Child" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }



    cell.childLoclong.text = appDelegate.longitude;
    cell.childLoclat.text = appDelegate.latitude;



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do some searching on reverse geocoding.

Answer (score 0):

Use this GET request link :

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=14.937681666666666,121.02107833333334&sensor=true_or_false

here  lat = 14.937681666666666 and long = 121.02107833333334

this is return one json and parse this json you have get **formatted_address** parameter and that is give you address from lat-long .

use it ..